# Blender animations how keep bone transform for current frame

Tags: animation

I'am trying to create push ups animation. I need put down body to the floor, bend elbows, but keep legs and arms in same place. 
So, the animation is more complicated, then it looks like, and I really have not idea how to do it. I think I have to create better Ik rig, but i do not which one and how. Do you have any ideas? tutorials?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you give your rig inverse kinematics this would be a lot easier. Set it up on the wrist and foot bones here is a good tutorial.
[tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0IhgS_us5U)

Comment: yes, i tried this, but i have already connected rig to the mesh. And when I adding Ik. I cannot add pole - cause it twist model legs,

Comment: This can be fixed by adjusting the pole rotation try something like -90.